# .htaccess make friendly url

Tags: .htaccess, url, friendly-url

I have a problem with making friendly URL. I need to convert url from `http://blabla.eu/stats_details?date=01-2012`  to `http://blabla.eu/stats_details/01-2012`. Other Rewrite rules are working properly beside the last one. What is the problem?

Here is code of `.htaccess`:

```
AddDefaultCharset utf-8

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^admin/users/$    /admin/users/view.php [L]
RewriteRule ^admin/loans/$    /admin/loans/view.php [L]
RewriteRule ^stats_details/(.*)$ stats_details.php?date=$1 [L,QSA]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: You say it should rewrite to stats_details?date=01-2012, in your RewriteRule you rewrite it to stats_details.php?date=01-2012

Comment: How is that possible? Other rules, for example, url /admin/users/view.php will be rewrited to admin/users that is to say left side of rewrite rule asks for final friendly url, right side for original url. Why did you decide so?

Comment: Re-read your opening question please, it just might be that you have typed a mistake.

Comment: Cannot understand why does it happen and how to fix it. Try a lot of variants to do it but the same result. Maybe, someone can find an error in the code.

Answer (score 0):

I think this must to work, try to paste

RewriteEngine On
        RewriteBase /

```
    # Removes index.php from ExpressionEngine URLs
    RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^GET.*index\.php [NC]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/system/.* [NC]
    RewriteRule (.*?)index\.php/*(.*) /$1$2 [R=301,NE,L]

    # Directs all EE web requests through the site index file
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
```